# Is there a way to programmatic refresh the excel WEB add in?

Tags: microsoft-excel, web-application

I need to update the add-in manifest and its cache frequently so I have to open the add in list dialog and click on the refresh button every time: can I do the refresh in programmatic way?

Comment: Yes it's possible,, but all depends on the Source Code used to create the AddIn,, whether is VBA or Java or PHP !!

Comment: It is web addin, introduced by office on 2016: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/overview/

Comment: [Check this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/tutorials/excel-tutorial#protect-a-worksheet),, now you have two situations,, whether you want to work with builtin Adins (which are password protected & difficult to unlock, so I could say non-editable),, another is created your own Adins,, for this the tutorial suggests Web based application, tools & languages. Better add new TAG to the questions `Web Applications` or `JAVA` or `HTML` , you get good response !!